# Exception thrown when stitching together two images using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-stitching

I am stitching two images together using `opencv-2.4.9` with Java in Eclipse. My code throws the following exception from `warpPerspective()`:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 3 && M0.cols == 3) in warpPerspective
```

`warpPerspective` method call:

```
Imgproc.warpPerspective(hsv, result, homoghraphy,
                        new Size(2 * input.cols(), input1.rows))
```

Type Of Homgraphy Matrix is:

```
scene = Mat [ 3*3*CV_32FC2,
              isCont = true,
              isSubmat = false,
              nativeObj = 0x7f32a0130160,
              dataAddr = 0x7f32a01301e0 ]
```

Could someone please explain why this exception is being thrown?

Comment: `scene` being a `CV_32FC2` might have something to do with the assertion failing, since it's looking for a `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`. However this is only speculation, if you're looking for an answer then you should edit your question and include more information. Such as: if you wrote the code to `warpPerspective` then that code would be useful, what the types and values are for `hsv`, `result`, `homography`, `input.cols()`, `input1.rows` ...

Comment: @Jonny yes.... it was because of matrix type scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with the type of homography matrix. Homography matrix is a single dimensional mathematical matrix.The homoghraphy matrix mentioned in the question was 2 dimensional array thats why it was not working. I have to change its type from **"2"** to **"1"** to make it work.